# Location Accuracy not working ionic 3.5.3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to use the [Location Accuracy](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/location-accuracy/) plugin but it is not working. I can test Native Ionic plugins via running "cordova run browser" and I see other native plugins like the Camera works just fine.

However, when I try to test the Location Accuracy, it says the plugin is not installed. I have tried everything (including the Google Play Services, etc) but nothing is working.

Any help?

Comment: Can you provide code how you include the `Location Accuracy` plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats correct. If you have a look at the [supported platforms](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/location-accuracy/#platforms) of location-accuracy plugin you will see that only Android and iOS are supported, not the browser platform. If you further check the underlying cordova plugins [`plugin.xml`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy/blob/master/plugin.xml) you will also see that there are only `<platform>` tags for Android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks a bunch David. I don't know how I missed that. But one question, why does canRequest() always return 0, regardless of whether or not my GPS is on? I was under the impression it should return true not false.

Comment: `0` is equal to `false`. If you have a look at the source-code [here](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy/blob/915b178faebd874f8a1a8b37c14590f7efb5b846/src/android/RequestLocationAccuracy.java#L244) you will see that the author chose `1` and `0` instead of `true` and `false`.

Comment: @David sir in the latest android version above plugin not working?